# Are daily reports not needed when reporting in bi-weekly meeting?

Tags: micro-management

I am working as a research engineer in a university lab for 32 hours per week via contract, but often work more than that (sometimes up to 50-60 hours) because there is a lot to be done and I really enjoy the work. My boss requires me to provide high level work updates (progress, issues, plan) in meetings via powerpoint twice a week (Tues/Fri). He also requests that I send

1. **Daily plan reports** when I start working (1 sentence plan for day) (so that he knows when I start working) and
2. **Progress reports when I am finished for the day** (hourly breakdown of work, breaks etc. --so that he knows when I stop working).

I have been doing this daily reporting for 7 months now (before COVID-19), and absolutely hate the lack of autonomy, micromanagement and trust. Are these daily reports necessary? If not, how do I communicate this to my boss? The only other person who sends daily plans/reports is the lab technician (he has weekly verbal meeting for 30 min).

**More on the job:** My job consists of writing software (low level C to high level GUIs) and designing and testing hardware (custom ICs, PCBs). My boss is proficient with hardware but not software.

Comment: We can't tell you if they're necessary or not, other than that your boss says they require them. You need to talk to them, not the Internet.

Comment: But also .. you say, *"so he knows when I start/stop working"* ... but is this actually the case?  I doubt it.  Your boss has various reporting requirements that you might never have thought to consider, and (s)he isn't going to burden you with them.  "Just smile, ever professionally," and give them whatever they say they need. You *really* don't know why they're asking, and, you really don't [have to] care.  (Maybe someday you'll be a manager yourself ... then you'll know.)

Answer (score 2):

> Are these daily reports necessary?

Could easily be. **It could easily be necessary without being useful.**  I was an employee of a startup in an accelerator and they required all manner of status updates and reports and hours for funding purposes. The grant providers who were providing the funds to pay us required them. Boss viewed it as utter nonsense, but we were required to do it.

It could also be that you are on contract and as a result the university wants an itemized list of things that they are getting for the contract. I work in the government and our contractors were required to do that.

Theoretically even I as a salaried employee in government am supposed to record hours like that, but I have made the exact same entry every day for 9 months now with a bot and nobody has complained or noticed. I can get away with that though because I am a salaried employee, making it just bureaucratic bloat. Nobody ever reads it, but if I miss filing it at the end of the month, 3 people get a notification that I forgot to do it.

That is the reality of large organizations.

Consider that your boss may not have any choice in these reports being required. Reporting requirements like these usually come from well above the people who need to implement them.

Even if your boss does have a choice, it may be in your employment interests that it continue. At a past job, the people who got to keep their contractors during cost-cutting were the ones who generated absurd amounts of paperwork that they were important.

Comment: Providing an hourly break-down of the time worked is quite normal. I've worked at some orgs where I needed to provide 2 in different formats: for my consultancy and the client. Providing it daily with detailed info on the starting/ end time and breaks isn't. Normally you provide it once a fortnight or similar.

Comment: @BigMadAndy our consultant was seemingly expected to update it daily.

Comment: Things like this:  "Cost accounting.  The obscure requirements of government grants.  The higher-level politics of the organization."  Could be absolutely anything – and, you'd have no clue.  (Nor would you be expected to.)  So ... "just smile a big smile and *do it."*   Don't "read into" these people's motivations ... you don't have their perspectives.  (Yet. *"Management is not for sissies ...")*